# Reading from /etc/environment with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, environment-variables, env

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I'm having a problem trying to read environment variables from `/etc/environment` when using `sudo env`. Basically, they are not being displayed. When I do just `env`, these variables appear like it should.

In my other server, which is running Ubuntu 13.04, both `sudo env` and `env` display variables from `/etc/environment`.

How do I get `sudo env` to read the environment variables set in `/etc/environment` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

**UPDATE - 2014-07-14**

I checked `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, and they are exactly the same:-

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Comment: `/etc/environment` is used by `pam_env`. Check `/etc/pam.d` on both hosts. I'm betting one of them is different.

Comment: @Patrick, I updated my question above. Both files are the same, am I checking the wrong files here? Thanks.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and `sudo env` works for me. It must be something other than distro version difference.

Comment: Check with `--login`; that will help remove sudo settings that could be allowing existing environment variables through. I've confirmed the behaviour with `--login` and I suspect that this is a bug.